# How to make MYSQL smart enough to understand when it should take into account stop word and when it shouldn't?

Tags: mysql

Ok, here is the problem. I have a table

```
Text
text nature ....
text2 nature ....
a lot of nature ... rows here..
....
go with nature
with nature her go it
```

Now, i select:

```
select * From MyFullText where MATCH(text) AGAINST ('+go +with +nature' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

As a human being, we will bring out only 2 rows:

```
Text
go with nature
with nature her go it
```

However, MySql is not human & it shows all rows that have the word "nature" since "go" & "with" are stop words so it doesn't take into account these words.

What if we have 1000 rows containing the word "nature"? if that is the case then user will waste a lot of time for searching.

In this case `like '%go with nature%'` does a much better job than fulltext.

So, can you find out an elegant solution that meets these requirements:

-Use "Fulltext ability for all non-stop words"

-If there are "stop words" in the search term then it should go back to use `LIKE` as in `like '%go with nature%'`

-Generally, it will be very smart to bring the best result depending on the search term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I state you have two possibilities with MySQL:

## Deactivate stop word list

You can deactivate the stop word list completely.

> To override the default stopword list, set the ft_stopword_file system
>   variable. [...] The variable value should be the path name of the file
>   containing the stopword list, or the empty string to disable stopword
>   filtering.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

([You might want to change ft_min_word_len too, since its default value is 4](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len) and "go" is only 2 characters long.)

This would allow you to use the fulltext index even in case of presence of stop words, which offers by far more possibilities than any search with `LIKE` and is a lot faster.

## Control the query

Your application can scan the search words before the query to actually change the query depending on "do the search words contain a stop word". If yes, query with `LIKE`, otherwise query with `AGAINST`. This way still leaves you with a very slow `LIKE` based query in the stop word case!

I do not know of further possibilities with MySQL as its capabilities concerning fulltext searches are rather limited.

## Non-MySQL-Options (Take a look around)

There is other software around, which eases problems of search&find, for example the modified MySQL code [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/). Sphinx obviously has a different approach than MySQL since [its default stop word list is empty](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/archives/1.10/conf-stopwords.html). If there even is the possibility to add another software to your infrastructure, you might take a look at its possibilities or search for other software which might fulfill your needs (e.g. [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/)).

Comment: "Control the query" is the best since if u remove all stop words then FullText search will be slow. Mysql said that. Besides, Like is much faster than FullText, based on my experiment it is about 3 times faster than FullText, the only downside of Like is it only search for '%searchTerm%' which will bring very small numbers of results

Comment: That is interesting. I would have expected the like query to be notably slower than the fulltext search. You can permute your search words around and build multiple or-connected like-clauses. `WHERE xxx LIKE "%searchWord%" OR xxx LIKE "%Wordsearch%"` and you also have the possibility to insert `%` signs in the middle of a search word.